# Rails: @category Vs @categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When should one use `@category` and when the plural `@categories`. Same with `@post` and `@posts`, etc.

Comment: Usually in the index action, you'll be listing a group of categories. But in new, show and edit, you'll be interacting with a single category.

Comment: Does the instance variable potentially refer to more than 1 object; Then plural otherwise singular. When do you say questions and when do you say question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a name, you can declare whatever with your variable but you should follow the convention.
You use the plural for a set of records and singular for only single record.

Answer (score 2):

When you're trying to get a group of records then use the plural term @categories. Normally you would use it like below:

```
@categories = Category.where(type: 'horror')
```

or

```
@categories = @movie.categories
```

When you're trying to hold a single record then go with singular term:

```
@category = Category.find params[:id]
```